# `to_datetime` limit or misuse? ValueError : Doesn't match format specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I can't seem to convert a series containing date strings into a `dtype` of `datetime64`.
The following code reproduces the error:

```
import pandas as pd

gud_date_s = pd.Series(["2019/12/31 00:00:00.0"]*100)
gud_date_s2 = pd.Series(["2261/12/31 00:00:00.0"]*100)
bad_date_s = pd.Series(["9999/12/31 00:00:00.0"]*100)
bad_date_s2 = pd.Series(["2262/12/31 00:00:00.0"]*100)


gd1 = pd.to_datetime(gud_date_s, format="%Y/%m/%d", yearfirst=True).dt.date # Correct
gd2 = pd.to_datetime(gud_date_s2 , format="%Y/%m/%d", yearfirst=True).dt.date # Correct
bd1 = pd.to_datetime(bad_date_s, format="%Y/%m/%d", yearfirst=True).dt.date 
#Returns {ValueError}time data 9999/12/31 00:00:00.0 doesn't match format specified.
bd2 = pd.to_datetime(bad_date_s2 , format="%Y/%m/%d", yearfirst=True).dt.date
#Returns {ValueError}time data 2262/12/31 00:00:00.0 doesn't match format specified.
```

So the threshold of accepted years seems to be `2261`. Why? How do I fix this?

N.B: dates such as `9999/12/31` are relevant, Therefore I would like to keep them as-is.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is not valid value year `9999`, so is necessary `errors='coerce'` for convert to `NaT`:

```
bd1 = pd.to_datetime(bad_date_s, format="%Y/%m/%d", yearfirst=True, errors='coerce').dt.date
```

And here is raised error, because [limit](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations), year is correct, but maximum month and day is only `11th April`:

Unfortunately here error should be more clear.

```
bd2 = pd.to_datetime(bad_date_s2 , format="%Y/%m/%d", yearfirst=True, errors='coerce').dt.date

print (pd.Timestamp.max)
2262-04-11 23:47:16.8547758
```

For working with datetimes it raise error:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime(year=9999, month=12, day=31)
bd1 = pd.to_datetime(bad_date_s, format="%Y/%m/%d", yearfirst=True, errors='coerce').dt.date.fillna(d)
print (bd1)
```

> OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00

Comment: Is there a way to keep the `9999/12/31` date?

Comment: give me a sec. I test it.